# Error running signed app on device

Tags: android, apk

I need to test the in-app purchase of my app. I've already done the tests with static response and everything worked fine.
In order to do that, I have added my email account to the account testers on developer console. After signed the app, I've uploaded it to the developer console, created the in-app item and installed the signed apk on my device.

When I launch the application it crash immediately saying "unable to instantiate application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExcpetion"

If I try to debug it, launching the app from Eclipse, it works fine, but with the signed apk I don't know why it crashes.

Any suggestion please? May it depend on an error creating the signed apk or in-app item?

**EDIT**
Here is the log:

```
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application us.care.MyApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: us.care.MyApp
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4120)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4645)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: us.care.MyApp
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
08-06 19:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(31950):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: If you're using Proguard, try turning it off.

Comment: @Exception-al I turned it off, but the crash happened later.

Comment: i was also having this error but i just tried making signed apk again and it worked fine without any change !! Strange but u can try creating apk again

Comment: @AmitHooda I've just tried but it still crashes...